# can't edit text area in JPanel Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I'm working on a gui program the allows you to open a JFrame with a txt file and allows you to copy and paste from a JMenu. But for some reason I cannot modify the text area after the txt file is loaded

heres my class with the methods, I have one that generates a JFrame I designed in my MyJFrame class and outputs a string in a scroll pane

the other method where I'm just trying to modify the that text area where the file is. I know this would be a lot easier if it was all in one class but my professor wants me to make this DisplayText method with the copy and paste methods.

```
public class DisplayText {

public JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

public void displayText(String title, String info)
{ 
   MyJFrame f = new MyJFrame(title);
   Container c = f.getContentPane();

   c.add(text);
   JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
   c.add(pane);

   text.append(info);

   f.setVisible(true); 
}

public void selectText()
{
    text.append("THIS IS A TEST");

}

public void insertText()
{
    text.paste();
}
}
```

heres the code where I put the action listener for the copy menu item, its in the MyJFrame class

```
item8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //copy menu item
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        dt.selectText();
    }
});
```

the copy button in the menu does not work at all and I'm not sure why, could you guys help me out? Thanks!!

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Why is `DisplayText` a separate class? I see no need for this. All you are doing is creating a text area and adding it to the frame. Keep that logic in the same class where you create all the other components. I suggest you start over and take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Text Compnents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for an example of how to better structure your code.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).